When I open my grease pencil file the text has all moved to a single point
When I open my grease pencil file the text has all moved to a single point. I relocate the text, save, and reopen the file, the text is back to the single point. I am using v4.2. It does not do this on other files created with v4.2. Also, I often find that I am on a different frame on many objects (text, lines, ect). I do not know how this happens. It is not intentional.
